# Psycopg2 INSERT query string composition with execute_values

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to insert data to a table in Postgresql using Psycopg2's  `execute_values()`. However, the job keeps on failing when I use "**string composition**". Is it possible to use string composition with `execute_values()` ?:

```
table='my_tab'
schema='my_schema'
col_lst = ['emp_id', 'emp_name', 'emp_age', 'emp_salary']
rec_lst = [('1234', 'John', 35, 10000), ('5678', 'Mike', 42, 15000), ('3452', 'Jason', 33, 15000)]
 
query = sql.SQL("INSERT INTO {schema}.{table} ({cols}) VALUES ({values});")
col_str = sql.SQL(', ').join(sql.Identifier(col) for col in col_lst)
place_holders = sql.SQL(', ').join(sql.Placeholder() * len(col_lst))
query = query.format(schema=sql.Identifier(schema), table=sql.Identifier(table), cols=col_str, values=place_holders)

psycopg2.extras_execute_values(cursor, query, rec_lst, page_size=1000)
```

**Error**: `The query contains more than one '%s' placeholder...`

Can anyone please help fix the same.

Thanks

Comment: 1) This `emp_age'` should be `'emp_age'` and is throwing everything else off. Not sure if this is copy/paste error or mistake in actual code? 2) `INSERT INTO {schema}.{table} ...` can be `INSERT INTO {table} ...` with `table=sql.Identifier(schema, table)`.

Comment: Also [execute_values](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#fast-execution-helpers)  needs to have the sql string just have `... VALUES %`. So you don't need to do `place_holders = ...` and `...values=place_holders`.

Comment: That should be `...VALUES %s`.

Answer (score 2):

Working example

Create table:

```
create table my_tab(emp_id integer, emp_name varchar, emp_age integer, emp_salary integer);

\d my_tab
                      Table "public.my_tab"
   Column   |       Type        | Collation | Nullable | Default 
------------+-------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 emp_id     | integer           |           |          | 
 emp_name   | character varying |           |          | 
 emp_age    | integer           |           |          | 
 emp_salary | integer           |           |          |
```

Python code:

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import sql
from psycopg2.extras import execute_values

table = 'my_tab'
schema = 'public'
col_lst = ['emp_id', 'emp_name', 'emp_age', 'emp_salary']
rec_lst = [('1234', 'John', 35, 10000), ('5678', 'Mike', 42, 15000), ('3452', 'Jason', 33, 15000)]

con = psycopg2.connect(dbname="test", host='localhost', user='postgres', port=5432)
cur = con.cursor()

query = sql.SQL("INSERT INTO {table}({cols}) values %s")\
.format(table=sql.Identifier(schema, table), 
        cols=sql.SQL(", ").join(map(sql.Identifier, col_lst)))


print(query.as_string(con))                                                                                                                                               
INSERT INTO "public"."my_tab"("emp_id", "emp_name", "emp_age", "emp_salary") values %s

execute_values(cur, query, rec_lst)
con.commit()

cur.execute("select * from my_tab")
cur.fetchall()    
                                                                                                                                                        
[(1234, 'John', 35, 10000),
 (5678, 'Mike', 42, 15000),
 (3452, 'Jason', 33, 15000)]
```